# Scaling and Stretching a Mesh

Tags: graphics, image-processing, mesh, style, scaling

I have a Voronoi mesh, given by

```
L1 = 5; L2 = 5; ar = Automatic;
pts = Flatten[Table[{3/2 i, Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, L2}, {j, L1}],1] // N;
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, AspectRatio -> ar]
```

[image]

If instead we set the aspect ratio `ar = 1`, we get

[image]

which is slightly different. This makes sense since `AspectRatio` is with respect to the image box size.

My goal is to scale this first image in the horizontal (or vertical) direction by a factor `scale`. At first I thought about using something like `AspectRatio -> scale`, but it doesn't work because of the `Automatic` inconsistency. Any ideas around this? Ideally I would like `scale = 1` to correspond to the first image, and then stretch the image from here.

I know about `Scale` and `Scaled` for a `Graphics` object, so maybe I could convert the mesh to a `Graphics` object? Any ideas?

This is a sketch of what I want

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the special form `ImageSize -> 1 -> {a,b}` for setting image size:

```
Row[Table[Labeled[
  VoronoiMesh[pts, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 20 {s, 1}],
  "s = " <> ToString[s], Top], {s, { .8, 1, 1.3, 2}}], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: So as far as I understood, a and b work as scaling factors in the x and y directions?

Comment: @samwolfe, that's right.

Comment: Just getting one annoying thing: whenever I evaluate the cell, select one of the output images and zoom in or out with the corner and side interactive widgets, the image gets automatically descaled, and I can't get it back to normal. Any way around this?

Comment: @sam, It may be a version/os-related issue. Interactive re-sizing works as expected in version 11.3 (windows 10 -64 bit)

Comment: I have the same OS. I meant manually re-sizing by holding and dragging. Does that work?

Comment: @sam, sorry spoke too soon. I had tried the panel with `s=1`. In other panels I have the same issue. To fix the issue  add the option `AspectRatio -> Full`.

Answer (score 4):

What if you scale underlying points of `MeshRegion`? That way you have complete control and you can use geometric transformation functions like `ScalingTransform`, `RotationTransform`, etc.

```
(* mesh comes form OP's code *)
newCrds = ScalingTransform[{2, 1}] /@ MeshCoordinates[mesh]
MeshRegion[newCrds, MeshCells[mesh, 2], Frame -> True]
```

[image: scaled_mesh]

Comment: If the mesh were 3D how would I use MeshRegion appropriately on the newCrds then? (I'm failing to apply it correctly.)